# Vuetify icons don't render at all

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

According to [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57057224/871404), the following code should render an icon with `Vuetify`:

```
<v-icon>
  arrow_downward
</v-icon>
```

It doesn't, instead I see "alarm_on" in plain text in the middle of a blue rectangle. No error in console, using `Vuetify` 2.0.0 and `Vue` 2.6.10. Below is how I add Vuetify to my project:

// Vue
import Vue from 'vue';

```
// Vuetify
import '@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css';
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib';
Vue.use(Vuetify);

export default new Vuetify({
  icons: {
    iconfont: 'mdi'
  },
});
```

Any idea why icons don't work?

Comment: How does your vuetify config look like? Especially the iconfont option (https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/icons)

Comment: are you import this module `import '@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css'` in app.js ?

Comment: Do you have this ?

import 'vuetify/src/stylus/app.styl'

Vue.use(Vuetify, {
  iconfont: 'md'
})

Comment: I added my config in the question. Yes I do import `materialdesignicons.css`. @JeffProd : `import 'vuetify/src/stylus/app.styl' Vue.use(Vuetify, { iconfont: 'md' })` isn't required in default icons installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use mdi prefix like that

```
<v-icon>
  mdi-arrow-down
</v-icon>
```

these are valid icons for mdi
https://materialdesignicons.com/